# Two sentences - same meaning?

Tags: negation, sentence-choice

> 1. I like to open my mind, but my mouth in a general discussion.
> 2. I like to open my mind, but not my mouth in a general discussion.

and

> 1. I have a cat at my home, but not a dog.
> 2. I have a cat at my home, but a dog.

Comment: How can they mean the same thing ? Are you sure you phrased the question correctly

Comment: Good question. +1. You need a comma *before 'but'*  to **exclude things**. But the sentence structure would be different. In such context, you group all things at one side and separate *one* thing at the other. For example, *"I like **all pets**, but a cat"*; *"I can withstand **anything,** but cold"*. If you have just two things, put *not* for better sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. The following sentences mean the same thing:

> 1. I like to open my mind, not my mouth, in a general discussion.
> 2. I like to open my mind, but not my mouth, in a general discussion.

and

> 1. I have a cat at my home, but not a dog.
> 2. I have a cat at my home, not a dog.

The correct usage of the sentence 1 in your first example and the sentence 2 in your second example using *'but'* would be:

> 1. I **don't** like to open my mind, but my mouth, in a general discussion.
> 2. I **don't** have a cat at my home, but a dog.

But this means exactly the opposite of its paired sentences.